# my traversal jquery don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

travel from .statPlus to select .secondTab, take a look on my js below.. In console.log(path), it show its own..

```
<div class='secondTab'>
    <div id='stat1' class='progress-radial progress-78'>
        <div class='profilePicture'></div>  <a href='#' class='percent'>78%</a>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- secondTab-->
<div class='statPlusWrap'>
    <div class='statPlus'>+</div>
</div>
```

js

```
  $(".statPlus").on('click', function () {
      var path = $(this).closest('statPlusWrap').prev('secondTab');
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a dot in your selectors, because you're selecting a class:

```
$(".statPlus").on('click', function () {
    var path = $(this).closest('.statPlusWrap').prev('.secondTab');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `.` for selecting classes, like this:

```
var path = $(this).closest('.statPlusWrap').prev('.secondTab');
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4mNC/)

Answer (score 0):

Typo missing `.` in [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
var path = $(this).closest('.statPlusWrap').prev('.secondTab');
                            ^// missing dot for class selector
```